# iOS: preview excel and word files

Tags: ios

I have an app that stores data and files in CoreData. Some files are photos, and I can display them, some are excel and word files. What is the best way to view them? Should I save em on filesystem and open with url? Does there is some controller in UIKit to display them?

Comment: Use `QLPreviewController` to preview your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to use QLPreviewController before

Check out this url for details

[QLPreviewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/index.html)

It's responsible for opening PDF, .XCL, .word files.

Or for a quick viewer you can load the files in [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/)